# Retrieve MySQL records which share common fields with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables which share common column called `id`.
 (but have not been set as `foreign key`)

```
+----------------+    +----------------+    +----------------+
| Table 1        |    | Table 2        |    | Table 3        |
+----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+
| id |  x  |  y  |    | id |  a  |  b  |    | id |  c  |  d  |
+----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+
|  1 | 0.0 | 0.0 |    |  1 | 2.0 | 6.0 |    |  1 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
+----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+
|  2 | 0.0 | 0.0 |    |  2 | 3.0 | 7.0 |    |  2 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
+----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+
|  3 | 1.0 | 1.0 |    |  3 | 4.0 | 8.0 |    |  3 | 0.3 | 0.7 |
+----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+
|  4 | 0.0 | 0.0 |    |  4 | 5.0 | 9.0 |    |  4 | 0.4 | 0.8 |
+----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+    +----+-----+-----+
```

In this situation, how can I get records containing fields `id, x, y, a, b, c, d` where `x = 0.0 and y = 0.0`

I expect the result:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| id |  x  |  y  |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 6.0 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  2 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 3.0 | 7.0 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  4 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 5.0 | 9.0 | 0.4 | 0.8 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I've googled with keyword `join` but as a newcomer, I'm a bit confused. Does this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
INNER JOIN Table3
ON Table1.id = Table3.id
WHERE x = 0.0 and y = 0.0
```

do the right thing that I expect? I don't see a sort of `select * from Table2` or `select * from Table3` things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` to get exactly the column you want, if you phrase the joins with `USING` rather than `ON`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN
     Table2
     USING (id) INNER JOIN
     Table3
     USING (id)
WHERE x = 0.0 and y = 0.0;
```

One caution is about using floating point values.  Often, these are not exact.  If you are using decimals, you should be ok.  But a `0.0` in the database might really be `0.0000000000001`, which would cause the comparison to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*, Table3.* FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
INNER JOIN Table3
ON Table1.id = Table3.id
WHERE x = 0.0 and y = 0.0
```

but you would get the id column 3 times in your result.

To get your exact result you need to pick explicitely the columns you want:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.x, Table1.y,
       Table2.a, Table2.b, 
       Table3.c, Table3.d
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
INNER JOIN Table3
ON Table1.id = Table3.id
WHERE x = 0.0 and y = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your query returns the resultset you specified, apart from returning some extra columns.

Here's an example of how I would write that query.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.x
     , t.y
     , u.a
     , u.b
     , v.c
     , v.d
  FROM Table1 t
  JOIN Table2 u  ON u.id = t.id
  JOIN Table3 w  ON w.id = t.id
 WHERE t.x = 0.0
   AND t.y = 0.0
```

Some notes:

If there is no "matching" id value in `Table2` or `Table3`, then no row would be returned for that `id` from `Table1`.

In MySQL, it's not necessary to include the `INNER` keyword, omitting has no effect on how the statement is executed.

When a query references more than one table, it's a good idea to qualify *all* column references, not just those with conflicting column names. (When someone adds a column named `x` to Table3, your query will stop working and will start throwing an "ambiguous column" error.)

I prefer to assign a short alias to each table, and qualify the column names with the alias.